# Many-to-Many EF Core already being tracked - C# Discord Bot

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, discord.net

So I'm using Entity Framework Core to build a database of Guilds (Another name for Discord Servers) and Users, with the Discord.NET Library. Each Guild has many users, and each user can be in many guilds. First time using EF and I'm having some teething issues. The two classes are:

```
    public class Guild
    {
        
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ulong Snowflake { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    }

    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        public ulong Snowflake { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public ushort DiscriminatorValue { get; set; }
        public string AvatarId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Guild> Guilds { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

    }
```

With the goal of having 3 tables: Guild, Users, and GuildUsers. This is my current function for getting the guilds:

```
 using var context = new AutomataContext();
            var discordGuilds = this.client.Guilds.ToList();
            var dbGuilds = context.Guilds;

            List<Guild> internalGuilds = discordGuilds.Select(g => new Guild
            {
                Snowflake = g.Id,
                Name = g.Name,
                CreatedAt = g.CreatedAt,
                Users = g.Users.Select(gu => new User
                {
                    Id = context.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Snowflake == gu.Id)?.Id ?? default(int),
                }).ToList(),
            }).ToList();



            // Upsert Guilds to db set.
            foreach (var guild in internalGuilds)
            {
                var existingDbGuild = dbGuilds.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(g => g.Snowflake == guild.Snowflake);

                if (existingDbGuild != null)
                {
                    guild.Id = existingDbGuild.Id;
                    dbGuilds.Update(guild); // Hits the second Update here and crashes 
                }
                else
                {
                    dbGuilds.Add(guild);
                }
            }

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I should note, a 'snowflake' is a unique ID that discord uses, but I wanted to keep my own unique ID for each table.

High level overview, guilds are collected into Discord.NET models. These are then transformed into internalGuilds (my guild class, which includes the list of users). Each of these is looped through and upserted to the database.

The issue arises in the second guild loop, where an error is thrown in the "Update" that a User ID is already being tracked (Inside the guild). So the nested ID is already being tracked? Not sure what's going on here, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What should happen with Discord guild users which do not exist in the database?

Comment: A good point, currently I believe it would try and set the ID to default int i.e. 0 and would cause the same Exception on two separate 'users not in the database'. Not however what has caused this initial exception as 1) The Id already being tracked is an existing user, 2) all the users from those guilds are currently in the database. well spotted though, definitely something  I need to consider, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This exception is most likely occurring because you are loading Users without tracking then looping through and potentially trying to update or insert guilds /w the same user reference, especially using the `Update` method.

I would suggest removing the use of `AsNoTracking`. Working with detached entity references via `AsNoTracking` is more of a performance tweak for when reading large amounts of data. You can pre-fetch all of the User references by their snowflake:

```
using (var context = new AutomataContext())
{
    var discordGuilds = this.client.Guilds.ToList();
    // Get the user snowflakes from the guilds, and pre-fetch them.
    var userSnowflakes = discordGuilds.SelectMany(g => g.Users.Select(u => u.Id)).ToList();
    var users = await context.Users
        .Where(x => userSnowflakes.Contains(x.Snowflake))
        .ToListAsync();
    // We need to add references for any New user snowflakes.
    var existingSnowflakes = users.Select(x => x.Snowflake).ToList();
    // If more detail is needed for new user records, it will need to be fetched from the passed in Guild.User.
    var newUsers = userSnowflakes.Except(existingSnowFlakes)
        .Select(x => new User { SnowflakeId = x }).ToList();
    if(newUsers.Any())
        users.AddRange(newUsers);

    
    List<Guild> internalGuilds = discordGuilds.Select(g => new Guild
    {
        Snowflake = g.Id,
        Name = g.Name,
        CreatedAt = g.CreatedAt,
        Users = g.Users
            .Select(gu => users.Single(u => u.Snowflake == gu.Id))
            .ToList(),
    }).ToList(),

        // Upsert Guilds to db set.
        foreach (var guild in internalGuilds)
        {
            var existingGuildId = context.Guilds
               .Where(x => x.Snowflake == guild.Snowflake)
               .Select(x => x.Id)
               .SingleOrDefault();

            if (existingGuildId != 0)
            {
                guild.Id = existingGuildId;
                dbGuilds.Update(guild); 
            }
            else
            {
                dbGuilds.Add(guild);
            }
        }

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This should help ensure that the User references for existing users are pointing at the same instances, whether existing users or new user references that will be associated to the DbContext when first referenced.

Ultimately I don't recommend using `Update` for "Upsert" scenarios, instead since the Db Record needs to be fetched anyways, updating values on the fetched instance or inserting a new one. `Update` will want to send all fields from an entity to the database each time, rather than just sending what has changed. It means enforcing a bit more control over what can possibly be changed vs. what should not be.